# Let $p$ be a prime number and let $G$ be a $p$-group. Then $G$ contains a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for every nonnegative $k\le r$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $G$ be a $p$-group: $|G|=p^r$ . Then $G$ contains a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for every nonnegative $k\le r$

But are there any normal subgroup of order $p^n$ such that $n>r$ ?

How can we show that, I couldn't show.

Comment: I mean, the order of $G$ is already $p^r$, so how do you want to define such a subgroup with more elements than $G$?

Comment: Yes my bad i thought $p^n$ as $n$ sorry. Thank you for your comment

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since Lagrange's Theorem ensures that the order of any subgroup of a group divides the order of the group; $p^n\nmid p^r$ for $n>r$.